# Evaluating text or string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, variables, evaluate

I have a React app and I have a dictionary of symbols stored in another file in the form of  securities.{asset}.symbol. For example, for Apple stock the address is stored at securities.Apple.symbol which normally evaluates to 'AAPL'.

So,

```
    let bb = `securities.${asset}.symbol`;
```

bb is now a string 'securities.Apple.symbol'
How do I evaluate the string above instead of returning a string?

I have tried

```
 let re = Function('return ' + bb)();
 console.log('res', re));
```

However that console.log doesnt return anything... (whereas if

```
  let bb=`1+1`
```

it would work and evaluate as 2)

Do you have a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Don't make `bb` a string and instead use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation): `let re = securities[asset].symbol;` to access your object key

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question:)